# How to find the number of occurrence in a string by Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and learning it by [solving IOI questions](http://www.ioi-jp.org/joi/2013/2014-ho/2014-ho-pr.pdf).

The first line of sample input file is the number of 'O'. If it is 1 then it needs to find 'IOI', if it is 2, then 'IOIOI' etc.

The second number 13 tells the number of character in the third line. The question is to find the number of occurrence of 'IOI'.

The following sample should give 4.

I made a method and using if statement in a while loop. But it gives an error with `ioioi.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)`. What I am trying in the while loop is to find if the first 3 characters are equal and if it is increase a `count` by one. and delete the first character and repeat the process.

Sample input file

```
1
13
OOIOIOIOIIOII
```

Output should be

```
4
```

My class Ioioi

```
def self.frequency(file_name)
    file = File.new(file_name, 'r').each_line.map(&:strip)
    count = 0
    o_str = file.shift # '1'
    o_num = o_str.to_i 
    findme = "IO" * o_num + "I"
    length = file.shift # '13'
    input = file.join
    while file.size > 0 do
      if file[0..(2*o_num)].eql?(findme)
        count +=
      end
        file = file[1..-1] # delete the first letter
    end
    count
  end
```

Comment: count += 1, presumably

Comment: remove `do` after the while statement it is not needed, `file = File.new(file_name, 'r').each_line.map(&:strip)` is same as `file = File.readlines(file_name)`

Comment: That IOI link is unfortunately not that helpful for English-speakers. What are IOI questions?

Comment: @bjhaid, have to remove an end if they did that, still wouldn't work either.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson don't get you

Comment: @bjhaid if the op removed the do after while, they would have an extra end...

Comment: I don't understand why this is on hold.  It was perfectly clear to me.  It would be a shame if @Wayne's elegant answer were condemned to darkness.

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions:

```
 def countem(n, str)
  str.scan(/I(?=#{'OI' * n})/).size
end

p countem(1, 'OOIOIOIOIIOII')    # => 4
p countem(2, 'OOIOIOIOIIOII')    # => 2
p countem(3, 'OOIOIOIOIIOII')    # => 1
p countem(4, 'OOIOIOIOIIOII')    # => 0
```

The regular expression looks for "I" (and consumes it), and then matches the rest of the string using positive lookahead, so that it is not consumed.  This leaves the remainder of the string available for more matches.

Comment: That's very cool, Wayne.  I've never thought of using a regex that way.  Good explanation too.

Comment: This is the perfect example of a problem best solved with a Regex look ahead.

Answer (score 2):

@Kyle has answered your question.  Here's one way to do it in a more Ruby-like way.

**Edit:** @steenslag has made two good suggestions for improvements to my code, which I'm happy to adopt.  Originally I had:

```
def countem(n, str)
  target = ('IO'*n + 'I').split('')
  str.split('').each_cons(2*n+1).reduce(0) {|tot,e| tot + (e==target ? 1 : 0)}
end
```

His main suggestion was that I use `count` rather than `reduce`, but also to construct `target` in a more direct way.  Those changes are reflected below.

**Code**

The key here is to make use of the method [Enumerable#each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
def countem(n, str)
  target = ['I','O']*n << 'I'
  str.split('').each_cons(2*n+1).count { |e| e==target }
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "OOIOIOIOIIOII"
countem(1, str) #=> 4
countem(2, str) #=> 2
countem(3, str) #=> 1
```

**Explanation**

```
n = 1
str = "OOIOIOIOIIOII"

target = ['I','O']*n << 'I'
  #=> ["I", "O", "I"]

a = str.split('')
  #=> ["O", "O", "I", "O", "I", "O", "I", "O", "I", "I", "O", "I", "I"]
b = a.each_cons(2*n+1) #=> a.each_cons(3)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["O", "O", "I", "O", "I", "O", "I", "O",
  #                  "I", "I", "O", "I", "I"]:each_cons(3)>
```

To view the contents of the enumerator:

```
b.to_a
  #=> [["O", "O", "I"], ["O", "I", "O"], ["I", "O", "I"], ["O", "I", "O"],
  #    ["I", "O", "I"], ["O", "I", "O"], ["I", "O", "I"], ["O", "I", "I"],
  #    ["I", "I", "O"], ["I", "O", "I"], ["O", "I", "I"]]
```

Lastly, count the elements of `b` that equal `target`:

```
b.count { |e| e==target }
  #=> 4
```

Comment: Thanks, @steenslag.  I originally tried `count`, but had a problem, so switched to `reduce`.  I don't know what I did wrong, but yes, `count` is much better.  I'll make the change.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an argument for the `+=` function, so Ruby is trying to read the next line as the argument. Instead, it's getting the `end` of the `if` block--but the `count +=` statement isn't complete, so it's not ready for the end of the block.